# Codeception Functional API tests with Laravel5 authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I'm trying to test an API that requires users to be logged in via Laravel through the web.  Javascript will be accessing a REST API with a CSRF token.  When I try to test this using Codeception it seems like the authentication is not being recognized with the `sendPOST` call.

I'm using the following Modules in my Api Suite:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
              depends: PhpBrowser
              url: http://app.dev/api/
```

Here is my test:

```
public function verifyFileIsRequired(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->amLoggedAs($this->user);
    $I->sendPOST(self::URL_GOES_HERE);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(422);
}
```

I keep getting a 401 response code. I have a feeling that this is due to the `sendPOST` method not sending the Laravel session info.  Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#sendAjaxPostRequest instead

Comment: That seems to work well! As long as the REST module is disabled.  Is there any reason to use the REST module & the Laravel5 module?

Comment: REST module has useful methods for inspecting JSON and XML responses.

Answer (score 1):

Naktibalda pointed me in the right direction to get this solved. 
Posting answer incase someone else runs into this problem.

In my api.suite.yml I should have had REST module depend on Laravel5.

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST:
            depends: Laravel5    <-- this was the fix
```